# Why is this call to the Google books API returning nothing in my API?

Tags: reactjs, go, backend

I am new to backend programming and am facing a problem that I'm not able to solve, even with ChatGPT. I have a backend server for a project that I'm building, using the Google Books API. To retrieve a single book volume, the URL is:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/zyTCAlFPjgYC?key=yourAPIKey
When I use curl and put in my API key together with a valid volume ID, I get the expected result, but when I do the same thing in my backend, this is the result:

```
kind    ""
items   null
totalItems  0
```

I tried to This is my frontend component that makes the API-call:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

interface BookVolumeInfo {
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
  authors: string[];
  publisher: string;
  publishedDate: string;
  description: string;
  industryIdentifiers: {
    type: string;
    identifier: string;
  }[];
  readingModes: {
    text: boolean;
    image: boolean;
  };
  pageCount: number;
  printedPageCount: number;
  printType: string;
  categories: string[];
  maturityRating: string;
  allowAnonLogging: boolean;
  contentVersion: string;
  panelizationSummary: {
    containsEpubBubbles: boolean;
    containsImageBubbles: boolean;
  };
  imageLinks: {
    smallThumbnail: string;
    thumbnail: string;
    small: string;
    medium: string;
    large: string;
    extraLarge: string;
  };
  language: string;
  previewLink: string;
  infoLink: string;
  canonicalVolumeLink: string;
}

interface BookSaleInfo {
  country: string;
  saleability: string;
  isEbook: boolean;
  listPrice: {
    amount: number;
    currencyCode: string;
  };
  retailPrice: {
    amount: number;
    currencyCode: string;
  };
  buyLink: string;
  offers: {
    finskyOfferType: number;
    listPrice: {
      amountInMicros: number;
      currencyCode: string;
    };
    retailPrice: {
      amountInMicros: number;
      currencyCode: string;
    };
    giftable: boolean;
  }[];
}

interface BookAccessInfo {
  country: string;
  viewability: string;
  embeddable: boolean;
  publicDomain: boolean;
  textToSpeechPermission: string;
  epub: {
    isAvailable: boolean;
    acsTokenLink: string;
  };
  pdf: {
    isAvailable: boolean;
  };
  webReaderLink: string;
  accessViewStatus: string;
  quoteSharingAllowed: boolean;
}

interface BookLayerInfo {
  layers: {
    layerId: string;
    volumeAnnotationsVersion: string;
  }[];
}

interface GoogleBooksVolume {
  kind: string;
  id: string;
  etag: string;
  selfLink: string;
  volumeInfo: BookVolumeInfo;
  saleInfo: BookSaleInfo;
  accessInfo: BookAccessInfo;
  layerInfo: BookLayerInfo;
}

const BookView = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [book, setBook] = useState<GoogleBooksVolume | null>(null); 

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const getBook = async (id: string) => {
    try{
      setLoading(true)

      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/search?id=${id}`)
        if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok")
      }

      const data = await response.json()
      console.log("Received book data:", data);
      //setBook(data)
    }catch (error) {
      console.error("API request error:", error)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   
    if (id) {
      getBook(id)
    }
    
  }, [id])


  return (
    <motion.div>
      {loading ? (
        <motion.div>Loading...</motion.div>
      ) : book ? (
        <motion.div>
          <h1>{book.volumeInfo.title}</h1>
          <p>Authors: {book.volumeInfo.authors.join(', ')}</p>
          <p>Publisher: {book.volumeInfo.publisher}</p>

        </motion.div>
      ) : null}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default BookView;
```

the route in my backend is this:
  `mux.HandleFunc("/search/:id", app.RetrieveBookByID)`

while the handler function is this:

```
func (app *application) RetrieveBookByID(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }

    apiKey := os.Getenv("API_KEY")
    bookID := r.URL.Query().Get("id")

    searchResult, err := app.books.RetrieveBook(bookID, apiKey)
    if err != nil {
        app.server_error(w, err)
        return
    }
    log.Println(searchResult)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    jsonResult, err := json.Marshal(searchResult)
    if err != nil {
        app.server_error(w, err)
        return
    }
    log.Println(jsonResult)

    _, err = w.Write(jsonResult)
    if err != nil {
        app.server_error(w, err)
    }
}
```

and the models function (if that is what you call it) is this:

```
func (b *BookServiceImplementation) RetrieveBook(bookID string, apiKey string) (GoogleBooksVolume, error) {

    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/%s?key=%s", bookID, apiKey)
    response, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        return GoogleBooksVolume{}, err
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()

    var searchResult GoogleBooksVolume
    err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&searchResult)
    if err != nil {
        return GoogleBooksVolume{}, err
    }

    return searchResult, nil
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and would really appreciate if someone could be of assistance!

Edit, here are my type definitions:

````
```


type BookVolumeInfo struct {
    Title               string   `json:"title"`
    Subtitle            string   `json:"subtitle"`
    Authors             []string `json:"authors"`
    Publisher           string   `json:"publisher"`
    PublishedDate       string   `json:"publishedDate"`
    Description         string   `json:"description"`
    IndustryIdentifiers []struct {
        Type       string `json:"type"`
        Identifier string `json:"identifier"`
    } `json:"industryIdentifiers"`
    ReadingModes struct {
        Text  bool `json:"text"`
        Image bool `json:"image"`
    } `json:"readingModes"`
    PageCount           int      `json:"pageCount"`
    PrintedPageCount    int      `json:"printedPageCount"`
    PrintType           string   `json:"printType"`
    Categories          []string `json:"categories"`
    MaturityRating      string   `json:"maturityRating"`
    AllowAnonLogging    bool     `json:"allowAnonLogging"`
    ContentVersion      string   `json:"contentVersion"`
    PanelizationSummary struct {
        ContainsEpubBubbles  bool `json:"containsEpubBubbles"`
        ContainsImageBubbles bool `json:"containsImageBubbles"`
    } `json:"panelizationSummary"`
    ImageLinks struct {
        SmallThumbnail string `json:"smallThumbnail"`
        Thumbnail      string `json:"thumbnail"`
        Small          string `json:"small"`
        Medium         string `json:"medium"`
        Large          string `json:"large"`
        ExtraLarge     string `json:"extraLarge"`
    } `json:"imageLinks"`
    Language            string `json:"language"`
    PreviewLink         string `json:"previewLink"`
    InfoLink            string `json:"infoLink"`
    CanonicalVolumeLink string `json:"canonicalVolumeLink"`
}

type BookSaleInfo struct {
    Country     string `json:"country"`
    Saleability string `json:"saleability"`
    IsEbook     bool   `json:"isEbook"`
    ListPrice   struct {
        Amount       float64 `json:"amount"`
        CurrencyCode string  `json:"currencyCode"`
    } `json:"listPrice"`
    RetailPrice struct {
        Amount       float64 `json:"amount"`
        CurrencyCode string  `json:"currencyCode"`
    } `json:"retailPrice"`
    BuyLink string `json:"buyLink"`
    Offers  []struct {
        FinskyOfferType int `json:"finskyOfferType"`
        ListPrice       struct {
            AmountInMicros int    `json:"amountInMicros"`
            CurrencyCode   string `json:"currencyCode"`
        } `json:"listPrice"`
        RetailPrice struct {
            AmountInMicros int    `json:"amountInMicros"`
            CurrencyCode   string `json:"currencyCode"`
        } `json:"retailPrice"`
        Giftable bool `json:"giftable"`
    } `json:"offers"`
}

type BookAccessInfo struct {
    Country                string `json:"country"`
    Viewability            string `json:"viewability"`
    Embeddable             bool   `json:"embeddable"`
    PublicDomain           bool   `json:"publicDomain"`
    TextToSpeechPermission string `json:"textToSpeechPermission"`
    Epub                   struct {
        IsAvailable  bool   `json:"isAvailable"`
        AcsTokenLink string `json:"acsTokenLink"`
    } `json:"epub"`
    Pdf struct {
        IsAvailable bool `json:"isAvailable"`
    } `json:"pdf"`
    WebReaderLink       string `json:"webReaderLink"`
    AccessViewStatus    string `json:"accessViewStatus"`
    QuoteSharingAllowed bool   `json:"quoteSharingAllowed"`
}

type BookLayerInfo struct {
    Layers []struct {
        LayerId                  string `json:"layerId"`
        VolumeAnnotationsVersion string `json:"volumeAnnotationsVersion"`
    } `json:"layers"`
}

type GoogleBooksVolume struct {
    Kind       string         `json:"kind"`
    ID         string         `json:"id"`
    ETag       string         `json:"etag"`
    SelfLink   string         `json:"selfLink"`
    VolumeInfo BookVolumeInfo `json:"volumeInfo"`
    LayerInfo  BookLayerInfo  `json:"layerInfo"`
    SaleInfo   BookSaleInfo   `json:"saleInfo"`
    AccessInfo BookAccessInfo `json:"accessInfo"`
}
```
````

And on the frontend:

````
```
interface BookVolumeInfo {
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
  authors: string[];
  publisher: string;
  publishedDate: string;
  description: string;
  industryIdentifiers: {
    type: string;
    identifier: string;
  }[];
  readingModes: {
    text: boolean;
    image: boolean;
  };
  pageCount: number;
  printedPageCount: number;
  printType: string;
  categories: string[];
  maturityRating: string;
  allowAnonLogging: boolean;
  contentVersion: string;
  panelizationSummary: {
    containsEpubBubbles: boolean;
    containsImageBubbles: boolean;
  };
  imageLinks: {
    smallThumbnail: string;
    thumbnail: string;
    small: string;
    medium: string;
    large: string;
    extraLarge: string;
  };
  language: string;
  previewLink: string;
  infoLink: string;
  canonicalVolumeLink: string;
}

interface BookSaleInfo {
  country: string;
  saleability: string;
  isEbook: boolean;
  listPrice: {
    amount: number;
    currencyCode: string;
  };
  retailPrice: {
    amount: number;
    currencyCode: string;
  };
  buyLink: string;
  offers: {
    finskyOfferType: number;
    listPrice: {
      amountInMicros: number;
      currencyCode: string;
    };
    retailPrice: {
      amountInMicros: number;
      currencyCode: string;
    };
    giftable: boolean;
  }[];
}

interface BookAccessInfo {
  country: string;
  viewability: string;
  embeddable: boolean;
  publicDomain: boolean;
  textToSpeechPermission: string;
  epub: {
    isAvailable: boolean;
    acsTokenLink: string;
  };
  pdf: {
    isAvailable: boolean;
  };
  webReaderLink: string;
  accessViewStatus: string;
  quoteSharingAllowed: boolean;
}

interface BookLayerInfo {
  layers: {
    layerId: string;
    volumeAnnotationsVersion: string;
  }[];
}

interface GoogleBooksVolume {
  kind: string;
  id: string;
  etag: string;
  selfLink: string;
  volumeInfo: BookVolumeInfo;
  saleInfo: BookSaleInfo;
  accessInfo: BookAccessInfo;
  layerInfo: BookLayerInfo;
}
```
````

This is what the api returns on success:

````
```
200 OK
````

{
"kind": "books#volume",
"id": "zyTCAlFPjgYC",
"etag": "f0zKg75Mx/I",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/zyTCAlFPjgYC",
"volumeInfo": {
"title": "The Google story",
"authors": [
"David A. Vise",
"Mark Malseed"
],
"publisher": "Random House Digital, Inc.",
"publishedDate": "2005-11-15",
"description": ""Here is the story behind one of the most remarkable Internet
successes of our time. Based on scrupulous research and extraordinary access
to Google, ...",
"industryIdentifiers": [
{
"type": "ISBN_10",
"identifier": "055380457X"
},
{
"type": "ISBN_13",
"identifier": "9780553804577"
}
],
"pageCount": 207,
"dimensions": {
"height": "24.00 cm",
"width": "16.03 cm",
"thickness": "2.74 cm"
},
"printType": "BOOK",
"mainCategory": "Business & Economics / Entrepreneurship",
"categories": [
"Browsers (Computer programs)",
...
],
"averageRating": 3.5,
"ratingsCount": 136,
"contentVersion": "1.1.0.0.preview.2",
"imageLinks": {
"smallThumbnail": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
"thumbnail": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
"small": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=2&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
"medium": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=3&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
"large": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=4&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
"extraLarge": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=6&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
},
"language": "en",
"infoLink": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&ie=ISO-8859-1&source=gbs_api",
"canonicalVolumeLink": "https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Google_story.html?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC"
},
"saleInfo": {
"country": "US",
"saleability": "FOR_SALE",
"isEbook": true,
"listPrice": {
"amount": 11.99,
"currencyCode": "USD"
},
"retailPrice": {
"amount": 11.99,
"currencyCode": "USD"
},
"buyLink": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&ie=ISO-8859-1&buy=&source=gbs_api"
},
"accessInfo": {
"country": "US",
"viewability": "PARTIAL",
"embeddable": true,
"publicDomain": false,
"textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY",
"epub": {
"isAvailable": true,
"acsTokenLink": "https://books.google.com/books/download/The_Google_story-sample-epub.acsm?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
},
"pdf": {
"isAvailable": false
},
"accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE"
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see your `go` type definitions that you are marshalling the API response to, but I suspect either the field names are not capitalized to allow them to be set - or the json tags do not match the API fields.

Comment: Thank you, I added the type definitions for the frontend and backend. Do they look right to you? The api documentation shows what is returned when you search for a specific volume: https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using